# CSS is broken - auto resize no longer works

Tags: html, css

I am having serious headaches with a site that I inherited, but did not originally create. Nearly all of the styling is done through one stylesheet. The problem is that the auto resizing no longer works, the pages all now appear at the smallest specified width. The css has become very clumsy as various different people have added to it over time. As far as I can tell, the resizing is controlled by several sections like this:

```
#bodyM #HeaderCentre, #bodyM #HeaderCentreFr, #bodyM #HeaderTitleConc, #bodyM #HeaderTitleConcD, #bodyM #HeaderTitleConcL, #bodyM #singleLine {width: 460px;}
#bodyL #HeaderCentre, #bodyL #HeaderCentreFr, #bodyL #HeaderTitleConc, #bodyL #HeaderTitleConcD, #bodyL #HeaderTitleConcL, #bodyL #singleLine {width: 630px;}
```

...and this:

```
body {width:700px; background:#fff; line-height:16px; margin:auto; font: 80%/1.2  verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif; color:#666; height:100%; }
#bodyM {width:800px;}
#bodyL {width:970px;}
```

Ie. there are three possible page widths, given by body, bodyM and bodyL styles. There are endless variants in the stylesheet specifying different font sizes, line heights and so on, to go with the body, bodyM and bodyL styles.

So what I would like to know is,

1. is there a simple reason why this no longer works?
2. is there a simple way I can get around it, ideally without having to change the whole stylesheet?

As you can tell, I am definitely more of an amateur than an expert!
For reference, the website is for bath choral society.

Comment: I assume that those additional body classes are added by js which is not loading now due to 500 error on file -> http://www.bath-choral-society.org.uk/screenSize.js I think you should check what is there at first.

Comment: Thanks for the quick comment. Do you mean the script is no longer saved where it should be? That could be the case, as the problem started after we updated the content management system (do not get me started on how useless cmsms is).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have stated in this thread, the problem is that you are missing `screenSize.js` which was providing a function called `getViewPortWidth();`.

If you can't find this file then it seems like all it was returning was an number so you could replace it by putting this into a file called `screenSize.js`:

```
function getViewPortWidth() {
  return window.screen.width;
}
```

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen/width

This is some really old code and as others have said it would be better to solve this particular problem with straight CSS now that media queries are supported in all modern browsers. Looking through your code it seems that `#bodyM` and `#bodyL` are used extensively. It would probably take a developer about 30 minutes to distil the stylesheets out but the theory would be to wrap an `@media` around each of the rules that use the `#bodyM` and `#bodyL`.

For example if your CSS file had this:

```
#bodyM #HeaderTitle h1, #bodyM #HeaderTitleConc h1, #bodyM #HeaderTitleConcD h1, #bodyM #HeaderTitleConcL h1, #bodyM #TwoPieceL h1, #bodyM #TwoPiece h1 {padding-top:23px; font-size:2.5em;}
#bodyL #HeaderTitle h1, #bodyL #HeaderTitleConc h1, #bodyL #HeaderTitleConcD h1, #bodyL #HeaderTitleConcL h1, #bodyL #TwoPieceL h1, #bodyL #TwoPiece h1  {padding:34px 0px 2px 10px; font-size:2.5em;}
```

You would replace it with this:

```
@media (min-width: 800px) {
  #HeaderTitle h1, #HeaderTitleConc h1, #HeaderTitleConcD h1, #HeaderTitleConcL h1, #TwoPieceL h1, #TwoPiece h1 {padding-top:23px; font-size:2.5em;}
}

@media (min-width: 980px) {
  #HeaderTitle h1, #HeaderTitleConc h1, #HeaderTitleConcD h1, #HeaderTitleConcL h1, #TwoPieceL h1, #TwoPiece h1  {padding:34px 0px 2px 10px; font-size:2.5em;}
}
```

To convert it I took these steps:

1. wrapped the `#bodyM` rules in `@media (min-width: 800px) { }`
2. remove the `#bodyM` bit from each of the wrapped rules
3. wrapped the `#bodyL` rules in `@media (min-width: 980px) { }`
4. remove the `#bodyL` bit from each of the wrapped rules

There is one exception to this, in the first few lines there are some rules like:

```
#bodyM {width:800px;}
#bodyL {width:970px;}
```

Removing `#bodyM` or `#bodyL` from those would break the CSS so you need to swap these two out (following the steps listed above) by replacing the `#bodyM` / `#bodyL` with `body`.

More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

The thing is though that this code is old and is targeting screen sizes that aren't really in use anymore. Your code is splitting the design at 700px, 800px and 980px which is hardly noticeable on modern devices. For example Bootstrap, the most popular css framework out there splits the screen sizes at the following px: 480, 768, 992, 1200.

In conclusion, this site is way past its use-by date and you should be looking for somebody to make a new template for you so that it works on modern devices such as phones, tablets and desktop computers :)

Comment: Thanks, yes I do realise the site is way out of date. To be honest, it was out of date 5 years ago! However I work on it for free in my spare time, and no-one has the expertise or time to completely redo it. I will be spending time on it over the summer, so maybe I can work out how to put in `@media`. Could you possibly point me to an example of how I would modify the style rules?

Comment: I've updated my answer to include a media query example. Appreciate this is a side project which is why I put the smiley face.

Comment: :) Thanks, that's amazing. Maybe I'll drag it closer to the 21st century after all...

Comment: Hi again - I realise this was ages ago, but I've only yesterday got around to updating the stylesheet. Thanks v much, it looks a lot better. I have one more related question - if I check pages on the website on my phone, text appears larger than normal and overflows the bottom of the template. This happens on many pages using different templates, so I guess must be something to do with the resizing? Do I therefore have to accept this?? @rtpharry any further info would be great :)

Comment: Sorry, haven't quite worked out this comment thing. Thanks again, @rtpHarry

Answer (score 2):

By looking at the website I have the following answers for you:

> a) is there a simple reason why this no longer works?

It looks like the body tag should be updated with a different id depending on the screen resolution. Looks like a script error which is not allowing the javascript to set the id: Uncaught ReferenceError: getViewPortWidth is not defined

> b) is there a simple way I can get around it, ideally without having
>   to change the whole stylesheet?

Yes, instead of detecting the view port, rather use media queries to adjust content depending on the resolution. Read about media queries here :

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

As a quick fix you could also add the following styles at the end of the stylesheet:

```
#body {
    width:100%;
    max-width:970px;
    min-width:700px;
}
```

I recommend using media queries, however the code above should resize the content between a maximum width of 970px and a minimum width of 700px.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. So you are saying the script is either missing or no longer working? That could be, as the problem started after we updated the content management system. The media queries thing is a little advanced for me, but I'll try and check it out...

Comment: Yes the function getViewPortWidth(); is missing. If you look at line 34 you will notice the missing function which is used to set the body tag id.

Comment: Looks like the function should be located in the file http://www.bath-choral-society.org.uk/screenSize.js file which is missing.

Comment: So I've just found this in the page template:                 `<script type="text/javascript" src="screenSize.js"></script>
</head> 

<body id="body"> 
    <script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
        currentWidth = getViewPortWidth();
        document.getElementById('body').id = currentWidth > 1000 ? 'bodyL' : (currentWidth > 900 ? 'bodyM' : 'body'); // ]]>
    </script>`     _I have no idea if this is correct or not!_ Sorry to be so hopeless.

Comment: Ok, I'll have to investigate when I get home from work, that js file must be saved somewhere... Thanks!

Comment: Yes, the script that you copied here is where the issue lies. Once you find the missing file which contains the missing function, this issue should be resolved. In the meantime, look into media queries :)